# Get the columns name of a Sharepoint list when the columns name has spaces in it

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I have code that gets all the items of a SP list and export it to CSV. In the code below I have specify the column called "00:00 - 07:59". But it doesn't work because the columns name got spaces in it. I could use the InternalName but I don't want that. Is it possible to get the name of a column that has spaces in it?

```
$ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "00:00 - 07:59" -value $_["00:00 - 07:59"]
```

Greetings, P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint powershell are always used InternalNames of Fields. If you want to export these properties, try create own Object with defined fields and names and insert into values, here you can use InternalNames and it will be user-friendly.

If you want more help, provide rest of the code for opportunity to change it.